Как сделать так, чтобы пользователь не мог закрыть всплывающее окно, пока не выберет определенный пункт? WordPress, Divi
Как сделать так, чтобы пользователь не мог закрыть всплывающее окно, кликнув по свободному месту, пока не выберет определенный пункт из предложенных. И только после этого окошко закроется само и даст доступ к сайту. Я использую плагин Green PopUp


Я использую плагин Green PopUp

Искать эти настройки в плагине или сменить его на другой, с нужными возможностями.
Иначе - писать свой плагин.
